# Applying rejections in Aggregates in Spine Event Engine

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, spine-event-engine

I am trying to apply a rejection to the aggregate which threw it:

```java
public class WalletAggregate extends Aggregate<WalletId, Wallet, Wallet.Builder> {

    @Assign MoneyCharged handle(ChargeMoney cmd) throws InsuffisientFunds {
        ...
    }

    @Apply void on(MoneyCharged event) {
        ...
    }

    @Apply void on(InsuffisientFunds event) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I can clearly see the `MoneyChanged` event applied. But when `InsuffisientFunds` is thrown, it is not applied. Am I missing something? How can I apply a thrown rejection to an aggregate?

Comment: I can see that the question is specific to the framework you use. I believe it makes sense to add it to the question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rejections don't work that way. A Rejection is more then just negative-case Event. It is emitted when an illegal operation is attempted and the handler (in your case, the Aggregate) refuses (**rejects**) to execute the Command, and thus does not change its state.

In practice, you might want to consider creating a separate entity that would process Rejections.
If you want to store the failed actions of a user, a `Projection` would probably work best:

```java
public class ChargeAttemptsProjection extends Projection<...> {

    @Subscribe
    void on(InsuffisientFunds rejection) {
        // Update the state of the Projection.
    }
}
```

If there is a flow for recovering from the faulty situation, a `ProcessManager` sounds more fit.

```java
public class FailedTransactionRecovery extends ProcessManager<...> {

    @React
    YourOtherEvent on(InsuffisientFunds rejection) {
        // Start the recovery process.
    }
}
```

Last but not least, there's always the possibility to subscribe to the Rejection on the client to handle it gracefully on the UI.
See [the JS reference documentation](https://spine.io/web/reference/client-js/Client.html) for more on client-side subscriptions.